# Search Product Name with few characters from each word which has got spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Need some help with the below requirement. Will explain through an example

Product name : "**AMOXICILLIN  SUSP 250MG/5ML  100ML**"

Client requirement is when they search the product like

a) "**amoxi**" or "**amo susp**" or "**amox susp**" or "**amo sus 250 100**"
b) **100 250 sus amo**  or **amox susp**

we need to display all similar product names like "amoxilin 10mg" or "amoxilin 30mg".Basically if the product name is too lengthy he is going to search the word using few characters from the different words in same product. Sometimes even reverse too should work like mentioned in point b. Looking for inputs to achieve this.

Thank you.
Prathap.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: What do you mean by *related products*? Another antibiotics or with similar product name?

Comment: Yes other products like "'amoxilin 10mg"  or "'amoxilin 30mg"

Comment: Then full-text search is a best solution. (See the link provided by Gordon Linoff)

Comment: Thank you. Started looking into it

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to break down the querystring into individual tokens, match each tokens against the data, count the number of tokens that have been matched and return only those result matching all the tokens.

Like so:

```
DECLARE @QueryString NVARCHAR(200) = 'amo susp';
WITH data AS (
    SELECT col = 'AMOXICILLIN SUSP 250MG/5ML 100ML' UNION ALL
    SELECT col = 'Other product'
),
QueryTokens AS(
    SELECT Token = X.n.value('.', 'nvarchar(200)')
    FROM (SELECT CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(@QueryString, ' ', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)) AS C(n)
        CROSS APPLY C.n.nodes('i') AS X(n)
),
NrOfTokens AS (
    SELECT NrTokens = COUNT(1)
    FROM QueryTokens
)
SELECT D.col
FROM data AS D
    CROSS JOIN  NrOfTokens AS NT
    INNER JOIN QueryTokens AS QT
        ON D.col LIKE QT.Token + '%'
        OR D.col LIKE '% ' + QT.Token + '%'
GROUP BY D.col, NT.NrTokens
HAVING COUNT(1) = NT.NrTokens;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

```
SELECT ProductName  
FROM TableName  
WHERE CONTAINS (ProductName, '"AMO*" OR "SUS*" OR "250M*" OR "100*"' )
```

Comment: But the values here are static in contains query. Can we change it to dynamic to search any product name

Comment: How do we send parameter in stored procedure for the same.

Comment: DECLARE @keywords(100)  
SET @keywords ='"AMO*" OR "SUS*" OR "250M*" OR "100*"' 
SELECT ProductName  
FROM TableName  
WHERE CONTAINS (ProductName, @keywords);